# Что же рубит рубанок?

Tags: этимология

Всем известно, что **рубанок** предназначен для того, чтобы строгать дерево делая его поверхность гладкою. Но корень слова явно указывает на другое действие. Возможно, когда-то функции рубанка выполнял все-таки топор? И "рубить", "вырубать" означало что-то вроде "сделать гладким с помощью рубящего инструмента"? И уже потом, когда для этого появился специальный инструмент, его назвали по названию действия.Впрочем, когда-то слыхал, что слово рубанок - немецкого происхождения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

рубанок - род. п. -нка (напр., у Л. Толстого и др.), укр. рубанок. Из нж.-нем. rubank, нов.-в.-н. Raubank "большой рубанок" (Сасс 10), "длинный рубанок для сглаживания неровностей, фуганок" (Кестнер, ZfslPh 21, 343; Граф, Wiss. Zschr. im Wartheland, 1943, 326; Фасмер, ZfslPh 20, 406), не через датск. rubank, шв. rubank, вопреки Маценауэру (LF 17, 181), потому что эти последние сами происходят из нж.-нем. (Ельквист 848; Фальк–Торп 907). Интересно отметить, что и нов.-в.-н. Fugebank заим. в русск. фуганок (см.). Связь с рубить носит исключительно характер народн. этимологии, вопреки Преобр. (II, 218); см. Маценауэр, там же. Фасмер, елки-палки.

А может это нарочно так делается?  Этимология от фонаря или/и от безнадежной  посредственности?

На немецком  слово рубанок имеет несколько значений:   первое   der Hobel,  второе  Flugzeug, 
Однако с обратным переводом---оба   --- синоним   самолет!!!! и это практически во всех европейских языках  рубанок---самолет.

Третье   значение -Ebene—уровень, как второе толкование.  А у них планировать.  PLANE(R) тоже рубанок-строгальщик, самолет и уровень.

Скобель - Dechsel  --тешель---тесло  если точно,  так и точно  у них  это струг и тесло в одном лице.
Тесло--- Querbeil—второй синоним, в переводе по корням---крест+топор. Но не смешно. Потому что есть que---cо значением палки. Русский мат. А есть axt—чисто топор. Beil—не иначе как русское било. Сравним зубило—голландский – beitel, немецкий – Meißel
Откуда и мебель. Читали скверно  букву готическую S?… Датский- mejsel
Или отметить надо переход—от написания буквы В   к произношению как  S
То есть   Ме́бель (фр. meuble, от лат. mobile)
Но и главное, русское присутствие в западной Европе видно по словам во всех языках, Но западники этого не видят, зато нам понятен смысл корней. Видно,  том числе и в латыни, сборной солянке монахов –католиков, сочинивших ее в средневековье, как бы наши лингвисты не убивались. А о западных и речи нет.

Вышеозначенное raubank    разберем дословно по корням.
rau bank  с немецкого  грубая скамья….. датский -  ru bænk, голландский - ruw bank
roi — в те времена еще королей царей величали, все для них, созвучненько не спроста.
В немецком  грубый  имеет синоним   grobe,
то есть  гроб—изделие из грубых досок, что и так у нас имеется до сих пор повсеместно.
гроб -- Sarg  , приехал к нам, вместе с немецкой грубостью. А у нас была домовина.
Рубанок для  этих досок. Изобретен обрусевшими немцами скорее всего.
Быстро прижился и не вернулся к немцам. У них рубанок—самолет-plane.
саркофаг Sarkophag    второй  корень от греч. phagos – пожиратель. А Погост для царьков..
корень царь  наблюдаем в обоих словах.
Цари царьки по исключению - в струганных гробах, можно и несколько в один.

Фу́га (от лат. fuga — «бегство», «погоня»)  то есть фуганок—быстрый!!!!
А вот фуга от испуга.
Струг---потом рубанок одинаково на западе – самолет-plane.
Что у нас стругом звали? не только инструмент, но и корабль. 
Корабль из досок, доски надо строгать, а рубанок—новый инструмент, старый струг.
Когда струги появились?  Когда появился инструмент.  Не раньше.
А на Волге в свое время  акционерная компания судовладельцев была,  общество—«самолет».
Третье - после обществ "По Волге", "Кавказ и Меркурий" - большое пароходное общество, созданное на Волге для перевозки пассажиров и грузов, называлось "Самолёт". Отставной капитан Российского флота Владимир Александрович фон Глазенап в 1852 году подал прошение - разрешить открыть дешёвое пароходное сообщение между Рыбинском, Тверью и Ярославлем. И в феврале следующего года разрешение получил. Основателями "Самолёта" были В. А. Глазенап и титулярный советник Максимилиан Густавович Бехагель фон Адлерскрон. Акционеры располагали основным капиталом в 250 тысяч рублей, разделённых на тысячу паев. Устав был высочайше утвержден 30 октября 1853 года.

Это при том при всем, что сегодня пишут : Слово «самолёт» применялось для обозначения летательных аппаратов ещё в XIX веке. Так, в 1857 году капитан 1-го ранга Н. М. Соковнин использовал это слово для обозначения управляемого аэростата.

То есть слово самолет—это в первую очередь быстрый корабль.
И не 19 веке, а гораздо раньше.  А что  печатно не было, так Церковь на все такое табу наложило. Как и в случае с латынью на западе, если понимала, что слова на самом деле означают. А у нас мат, родная речь. Но там точно не понимала, на севере Европы кругом одна речь-«славянская», как Священной римской империи не набраться, и набралась с миру по нитке. И как не насочинять, новой Истории, если надо, во имя благой цели подмять под себя весь мир, огнем и мечом. У нас не прошло, смягчилось. Но на языке сказалось.
У меня к нашим историкам вопрос имеется, а для чего у нас монастыри крепостные стены строили не хуже городских, от кого? От прихожан или иностранцев?

Короче, если читать Фоменко с Носовским вдумчиво, принять во внимание датировки и нормальную, смысловую лингвистику, то получается с официальной историей пора завязывать. Я не очень- то поддерживаю их версию,  пока, есть нестыковки. Но,  в общем они правы.

А откуда  самолет?  Само—это понятно. А вот лЁт.
От  летать  это точно? А может от лед?  Два слова, а как близки. На лед вступил, скользко и полет.  По лед.
Вот и еще одна ассоциация. 
О дальше еще цепочка---лодья, не ладья…..  ПОЛЕ ЛОДЕЙНОЕ.
Лодка. По льду катится, если толкнуть.

Лот—инструмент—отвес с узлами глубину измерять.
Понятно откуда взялось слово.
Отвес во многих языках  -лот.

Pilot-----пай-лот.    Хороший лот.
Lotsman. Измеряющий глубину.

А скорее всего самолет от лед. Скорость определяли по льдине сначала на глаз, а потом и веревку цепляли, с узлами, чтоб поточнее.
А еще таким отвесом и глубину меряли.
И не ладья, как по-нынещнему, а лодья, а уж потом лодка.
Судно для плаванья и перетаскивания по льду.
Продолжение следует…

Comment: Столько слов - и все мимо.

Comment: Мимо вас, я в вас и не целился.

Comment: мимо сути. А я и не претендую на должность мишени.

Comment: а кто вам сказал, что я по Вашей сути целюсь, у меня цель другая.

Comment: Может хватит на личности перехордить?
Вам до моей сути =- сем верст и все лесом.

Comment: А вы меня в этом плане и не интересуете, а суть она ваша, уже понятна, безотносительно к сути вопроса,  который вы даже обсуждать не пытались, одни реплики провокаторские. Вы к модератору уже бегали.

Comment: Я Вам поставил Выбор ответа. За рубанок именно. И остальное любопытно. Но много от Задорнова . Больше для улыбок.

Answer (score 6):

Можно вывести от нем. *Raubank* «(большой) рубанок», далее из *rau* «шершавый, шероховатый» + *Bank* «верстак, станок»?. В русск., укр. и белор. — сближено с рубить.

То что слово фуганок (большой рубанок) заимствованное точно сомнений не вызывает (от нем. *Fugbank*).

Копипаста из викисловаря. В конечном счете первоисточник - [Макс Фасмер](http://vasmer.narod.ru/p595.htm)

**UPD**
[[@grumant](/users/1349/grumant)](/users/1349/grumant),

Сложно судить. Если бы утверждали, что [медведка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)), [струг (скобель)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C), строганок - русскоязычные термины, то я бы возражать не стал. По поводу того что есть что интересно написано у [Броугауза и Ефрона](http://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%A1%D0%91%D0%95/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE). Они утверждают, что рубанок - вполне конкретный инструмент с вполне конкретным назначением, а не название целого класса инструментов. Я думаю, что немецкий след имеет право на жизнь, хотя бы потому что количество немцев в России всегда было ощутимо (собственно, наверное, поэтому их и стали называть "немцами", т.е. не говорящими по-русски, а не, скажем, германцами?). И были они специалистами в своих областях - кто столяр, кто токарь, кто плотник, кто ткач. Были среди них естественно и крестьяне.

Comment: Насчет того, что "немцы" - оттого,что непонятно говорят - большой вопрос. В романских и других языках используются корни от названия германского народа алеманнов,в арабском(almāniyy — الألمانية) и турецком языке(Alman).Используются названия и других германских племён: saksa — от племени саксов (в эстонском языке),bawerski — от племени баваров(в лужицких языках.Восточными славянами и балтами для обозначения германцев использовался термин «тевтоны», ведущий от латинского названия германских племён «Teutoni».Возможно,что и племя "неметов" дало название "немец" у русских и других славян.

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно, когда-то функции рубанка выполнял все-таки топор?

Нечто подобное имело место, но это процесс назывался, если не ошибаюсь, *скоблением*.
Остальное - у [@gecube](/users/972/gecube)

Comment: эти приспособления назывались: струг, заструг, скобель, тесло, зубило, и еще много.

Comment: Зубило выполняло функции топора?
Не смешите женщину.
"Ляпсус, Вы домкрат когда-нибудь видели?"

Comment: У нас зубило--это импортная стамеска. По русски еще долотом называется. Но шире.

Comment: Ну а причем тогда это здесь?

>>Возможно, когда-то функции рубанка выполнял все-таки топор? 

>>эти приспособления назывались: струг, заструг, скобель, тесло, зубило, и еще много.  

Где топор - и где зубило. Вы еще астролябию вспомните. Или кадило.

Comment: А  не строгали, и не надо было рубанка, и других инструментов,  Кололи дерево вдоль, клиньями, вас не спросили.